# Intellisense complains that "namespace std has no member size_t". How can I remove this (false) error?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, msys2

Using Visual Studio 2019, "open folder" project. Msys2, mingw64.

Build completes without any issues, but IntelliSense complains:

> namespace "std" has no member "size_t"

IntelliSense also lists ~5700 other (false) errors, but I guess they're all related.

How can I configure IntelliSense properly, so that it does not display false errors like the one I have mentioned?

```
// CppProperties.json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mingw64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\**",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\include",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\9.1.0",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\9.1.0\\x86_64-w64-mingw32",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\9.1.0\\backward",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\9.1.0\\include",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\9.1.0\\include-fixed",
        "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
      ],
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-clang-x86",
      "environments": [
        {
          "PATH": "C:\\tools\\msys64\\usr\\bin",
          "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64",
          "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// .vs/tasks.vs.json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "build",
      "appliesTo": "*",
      "contextType": "build",
      "type": "default",
      "command": "bash.exe",
      "args": [
        "--login",
        "-c",
        "\"sh build.sh\""
      ],
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "Mingw64"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I suggest you could close your VS Instance, enter your project folder, delete `.vs` hidden folder,`bin`,`obj` folder and then restart your project. Then test again.

Comment: It seems that you have created a c++ project in vscode and then migrate it to visual studio. Could you please share a code sample with us?

Answer (score 2):

> Intellisense complains that “namespace std has no member size_t”. How
>   can I remove this (false) error?

The projects created by VS Code and VS are inconsistent, they have different structures, so if you migrate from VSCode to VS, there will be many problems.

In VS, in general, there is a `xxx.vcxproj` project file in C++ project to control the files' structure and then MSBuild reads the `xxx.vcxproj` file to build your project. And when you open the project, you should use `xxx.sln` or `xxx.vcxproj` file.

And in VS Code, usually in a folder is a cpp file combined with a `task.json` and other files to build or debug. If you import it into VS, it is just a folder with those cpp files and json files which are not consistent with the project structure in the VS IDE.

**After all**, in VS, [the header file is stored in the project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019), while vs code stores the file address in the `xxx.json` file. You can create a c++ console project in VS to compare, right-click on the project-->`Properties`-->`VC++ Directories`-->`Include Directories`.

[image]

Those above are just to explain the difference between VS and VS IDE.

**Suggestion**

**1)** first, make sure that you have import this:

`#include <iostream>`

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, output file and then reopen your project, rebuild several times to test it.

**3)** try to create a new c++ project in VS and then migrate your vscode c++ projects into it(copy cpp files into it and config the related libraries in my way). And please maintain a consistent structure in VS IDE.